# Installing ubuntu as dual boot for windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

Hey i'm looking to install Ubuntu with dual boot for windows 10 however a friend of mine told me there is a concern that it will slow down my computer performance.
Is that true?? and if so is there a better way to run Ubuntu instead.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Now it does not slow down the computer. What do you mean by a better way? The titel and the body of the question do not match. Please read the following https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A dual boot system (*be it two or more OSes*) does not cause any to run any slower than if they were the only OS installed, it's just one is running whilst the other is just unused on disk/ssd. Yes it adds complexity to the partitioning on disk, but as only one is running, it's not impacted by the other at all. Regardless of your approach, there are pros & cons for everything, but speed of execution isn't impacted by dual booting (be it two OSes installed; or you dual boot a Ubuntu, Windows & BSD or any combination).

Answer (score 2):

> Is that true??

No. It's not true. Your friend may offer good advice on other topics (or not, we don't know them), but their particular advice on this subject is flat wrong.

Software that sits on disk, unused, does NOT slow the functioning of a computer. That's just how computers work.